# no puedo lograr añadir mi prolog executable path a vs code Cannot lint the prolog file. The Prolog executable was not found

Tags: vscode, prolog, swi-prolog

no consigo añadir exitosamente el executable path a vs code, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad4c6.png)

`Cannot lint the prolog file. The Prolog executable was not found. Use the 'prolog.executablePath' setting to configure`
ya añadi el path a las variables de entorno `C:\Program Files\swipl\bin`, segun yo estoy usando la ruta hacia el archivo correcto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y este es mi settings.json [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] ademas estoy usando las extension vsc prolog
ya intente de todo pero no consigo solucionarlo seria muy util si alguien supiera que hacer

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón apra que no uses el editor por defecto que trae tu swi prolog? Allí te menciona que modifiques la configuración `prolog.executablePath` (ya que por lo visto el plugin es tan chafa que no toma la ruta del ejectable desde las variables de sistema)